# Most-frequency number

Tags: python, frequency

Yes there are lots of topic about this. but my question is different.
I wrote my code and it is;

```
A = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7]

def countFreq(A):
    n=len(A)
    count=[0]*n                     # Create a new list initialized with '0'
    for i in range(n):
        count[A[i]]+= 1              # increase occurrence for value A[i]
    result = []
    for x in count:
        if x:
            result.append(x)
    return result
print(countFreq(A))
```

output is;

```
[1,1,1,3,1,5,3,6]
```

that means, how many numbers there are, that function it counted.
there is one "1" and there are five "6" and six "8" etc.

but I want to just seeing most frequency number. as that code, just seeing 8.
how can I do? Please show a way with my code. not different code.
I don't want to built-in function or any ready code.
please see a way just in my code.

edit: Actually, I want to see from my code's output;

```
A = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7]
Most-frequency number is : 8
```

or

```
A = [1,2,3,3,3]
Most frequency number is : 3
```

or

```
A = [1,1,1,2,3,4]
most frequency number is : 1
```

I want this..

edit: In my question, teacher give us a hint, this is;
"Hint: You may consider recording the number of occurrences of each digit in a new list, whose indices will be mapped to the input digit values."

Please anyone that see it, show me a way with my code...

Comment: so then, where is the answer?

Comment: You picked up correctly on the hint your teacher gave you. Now all you want is the index of the highest value in your list.

Comment: @usr2564301 but how? indexes are different in output. I don't understand :/ can you show me

Comment: No. The *indexes* are not different. The index is the part that goes `0,1,2,...` - and the *nth* index of your array contains the count for number *n*.

Comment: @usr2564301 That's essentially what I've done in my answer.

Comment: @usr2564301 I don't know how to write. can you show me with code?

Comment: @Adi219 I said that. your code is not right. output is wrong.

Comment: It'll work now (there was a simple error)

Comment: @Adi219
No. It's still wrong. If you want to understand. You can run your code with my function. and you see.
There is no call. in that code, it is not calling my function and if I change it, it still give a wrong value.

Comment: @user9654395 I thought you understood that the function had to be called first ... I've edited my answer (again!)

Comment: @Adi219 It workes. thank you. I can use that code. but I don't know is it necessery but I ask you, for example there is; A = [1,1,2,2,3]
and should answer is 2 and 1?
because in your code answer is 1 or 2.
but normally it is true. you think is it necessery?

Comment: I can edit my answer to suit this, but honestly, I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: Of course. It helped me thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `print()` statement to `print(countFreq(A).index(max(countFreq(A))) + 1)`.

Comment: but ready function not accepted because of my school. Is there any way that not with ready code?

Comment: @user9654395 There's a way, but it's *very* inefficient and requires loops, which aren't needed. Are you sure you're not allowed to use `max()` ?

Comment: @user9654395 If you aren't allowed to use built-in functions or methods how come you're using `range`, `len`, `.append`, and `print`?

Comment: #Adi219 We see max. but we didn't see index @PM2Ring actually we don't use print too. but I can convert print to my real code. but I can't that I asked. but others are accaptable in my school. I mean, If I didn't say that, answers would be related about count or collections. They are not acceptable. I hope you understand.

Comment: @user9654395, I get the gist, but can you **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50085847/edit)** with your **specific requirements**. The reason is your question becomes something completely different with these criteria.

Comment: How about you code your own `max` function? That way you aren't using predefined functions.

Comment: @AbhishekSoni Since they're using so many predefined functions, surely they can use `max()` ? If they can't, they could just Google it's definition.

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code. A better way is to restructure your logic is to use a dictionary.

The Python way is to use `collections.Counter` or, since you want to expose logic, `collections.defaultdict`:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7]

from collections import defaultdict

def countFreq(A):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for item in A:
        d[item] += 1

    maxval = max(d.values())
    maxnum = [k for k, v in d.items() if v==maxval]
    return maxnum

print(countFreq(A))
```

Comment: Problem is, they dont want any predefined functions or classes or changes to their code. 

Comment: collection is not accaptable in my school. buy in that question teacher give us a hint, this is "Hint: You may consider recording the number of occurrences of each digit in a new list, whose indices
will be mapped to the input digit values."

so can you show me a way, with my code? please. I tried many times but i didn't find.

Comment: @Adi219, All these restrictions need to be **explicit in the question** ("I don't want to built-in function or any ready code" is unclear). Until then, this answer is acceptable even if it doesn't help OP. Maybe the next user will find it helpful.

Comment: @Adi219 I tried your way to. but you didn't call the function. and when I write your instead of my print. answer will be 14. It's wrong.

Comment: @jpp Actually, OP says 'Please show a way with my code. not different code.'

Comment: @Adi219, The problem is there are *too many problems* with the code. Feel free to answer yourself given all these poorly defined restrictions.

Comment: @jpp I agree, but I just wish to point out that I ***have*** answered the question (despite 'these poorly defined restrictions').